# how to get rspec to show what it found on failed tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I wrote an rspec test `it { should have_title("Title | Subtitle") }`

When I go to said page from localhost I see the correct title displayed, however, when I run my rspec test, I get:

```
Failure/Error: it { should have_title("Title | Subtitle") }
       expected #has_title?("Title | Subtitle") to return true, got false
```

How can I ask rspec to print out the title it found instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_title?` is a capybara matcher. rspec is not involved there, that matcher just returns true or false.

if you want to get the title, you need to do something like `expect(page.title).to eql('blah')`

Comment: I have the capybara installed under test, version 2.1.0 I believe so I'm not sure why it doesn't work, but I'll try this.

Comment: It doesn't work because I have my tests written in a different way. subject { page }
describe "About Page"
before { visit about_path }
it { should have_title("DropShare | About")}
    it { should have_content('About') }
  end

Comment: then rewrite your tests